# Sync the directories

Tags: rsync

I have a directory on the computer having many files and sometimes I need to sync it with a clone from a device.

I use rsync.

Rsync does not see when a file was renamed or moved in other directory and it is very slow sometimes.

Is there a smart syncing tool that can see when a file was renamed/moved in the main directory and just rename on the clone without physical remove+copy ?